# Add and edit words to Magento 2 language dictionary

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, localisation, language

In Magento2 - I have installed language pack from **MagePlaza**. Most of the words got translated, I need to edit the untranslated words. I edit in this file

```
app/i18n/mageplaza/da_DK.csv
```

and deployed static, cleaned and flush cache, but nothing changed.

What should I do to edit/add translation?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same problem with changing / adding stuf in the `app/i18n/` directory.
We added the translation file in `app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[custom-theme]/i18n/da_DK.csv` Hopefully this help.